# Lexically recognized synonym for "humblebrag"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, synonyms, pejorative-language

As one might guess, a *humblebrag* is one who uses a pretense of humility as a vehicle for boasting.  This word can be found at Urban Dictionary but, it appears, nowhere more authoritative.  Yet, of course, the concept is neither new nor esoteric; and one would expect there to be a word to cover it.  Of course, we have the idea of *false humility* and could speak of one who is *falsely humble* or who is guilty of *false modesty*.

But isn't there a noun to denote the person who behaves in this way, and an adjective to describe him?

Comment: Demanding a single word for a concepts is misdirected. Sure it'd be nice, but a multi-word description works just as well. I mean, ow did people survive before that word was coined?

Comment: There's an interesting entry for _humblebrag_ at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/humblebrag). It shows a few contemporary uses, yet the word also shows up on these lists: _Outcasts_ (Words that people on Twitter don't think are words), and _New and Unholy Coinage_ (21st century coinage; any strange words seen on TV or heard from irritating young people). Oh, well; I'm sure it's not the first word to start with such wobbly beginnings.

Comment: What does “lexically recognized” mean?

Comment: OK, if there is no single, longstanding word for this specific concept, so be it.  It just seemed to me not unreasonable to expect that there might be.  After all, we're not always limited to designating a person or trait using a selection of adjectives and nouns rather than a single, specific, powerful word.

Comment: And by "lexically recognized," I just meant it would appear in a published lexicon of English.

Comment: The earliest reference I can find is 21 April 2011, so it's new. But the word isn't going to get into dictionaries without becoming established first. Use it!

Comment: @Andrew: Parks and Recreation writer Harris Wittels wrote on [June 15, 2011](http://www.grantland.com/story/_/id/6665462/humblebrag-hall-fame): "So, about a
year ago, instead of just silently griping about it
to myself, I gave it a name and started an account
on Twitter on which I retweet Twitter's most
flagrant Humblebraggers (www.twitter.com/ humblebrag)." The account was created on 12 Nov 2010.

Comment: @Andrew: The first post by humblebrag is a retweet from [Nov 11th 2010](https://twitter.com/Humblebrag/status/2886269772234752); [Harris said:](http://articles.latimes.com/2012/sep/14/entertainment/la-et-cm-humblebragging20120914) *humblebragging started as an inside joke on the set of "Parks."*. // The earliest I found in Usenet is [Mar 2, 1997](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rec.pets.dogs.activities/19qfeGflwfY), but it's not quite got the same meaning.

Comment: **humblebrag** noun *something a celebrity says which sounds humble or self-effacing, but which actually contains an element of boasting* http://www.macmillandictionary.com/open-dictionary/entries/humblebrag.htm

Comment: Related: *[Is there a word to describe one who brags by complaining?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142056)*

Answer (score 3):

A term you might consider if you want to appear modestly learned is Aristotle's ***eirôn***, a noun variously translated as ‘the mock-modest’ or ‘the self-deprecating’ or ‘the reserved’. Aristotle describes the *eirôn* as more acceptable than the *alazôn*, ‘braggart’ or ‘exaggerator’ but not so admirable as the truthful man:

> Mock-modest people, who understate things, seem more attractive in character; for they are thought to speak not for gain but to avoid parade; and here too it is qualities which bring reputation that they disclaim, as Socrates used to do. Those who disclaim trifling and obvious qualities are called humbugs and are more contemptible; and sometimes this seems to be boastfulness, like the Spartan dress; for both excess and great deficiency are boastful. But those who use understatement with moderation and understate about matters that do not very much force themselves on our notice seem attractive. And it is the boaster that seems to be opposed to the truthful man; for he is the worse character. —*Nicomachaean Ethics*, IV, 7

*Eirôn* gives its name to *irony*; the word itself doesn't appear to be in the dictionaries, but it had considerable currency in the LitCrit industry for the generation after Northrop Frye made the term central in *The Anatomy of Criticism* (1957). You'll find it in Abrams and Harpham, *A Glossary of Literary Terms*. Here's a modern [history](http://books.google.com/books?id=6EAw-H8zvDkC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=Eiron+Aristotle+Theophrastus&source=bl&ots=0vDZ0Ro-Zb&sig=9T8EZti_Su40nhm3p8ljZPUqjak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Rw3qUOeIHMKA2gXko4HwBQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Eiron%20Aristotle%20Theophrastus&f=false) of the term from a 1991 work, *The Critical Mythology of Irony*.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=humblebrag&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop) definition of *humblebrag* is:

> An ostensibly self-deprecating statement made to show off.

A [London Evening Standard article](http://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/gain-sweet-revenge-on-twitter-trolls-7308265.html) says:

> Meanwhile, the
>   "humblebrag", where users take a "What, little
>   me? How can I have won another award?"
>   approach, has been exposed for what it really is: showing off under a façade of humility.

So you could just call them a *show-off*, *boaster*, or *bragger*, because despite any vaneer of  humility the point is they are still *showing off*, *boasting*, or *bragging*.

There's nothing wrong with the *false modesty* of the *falsely modesty*. A [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/12/02/fashion/bah-humblebrag-the-unfortunate-rise-of-false-humility.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) on the *humblebrag* uses the following terms to describe it and its users:

*False modesty, faux
 humility, sophisticated braggers, bad manners, self-deprecating boast, the attention-
starved, bragging, falsely modest statements, falsely modest people.*

Answer (score -1):

While inexact, I suppose that such a person could be called a [poseur](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poseur):

> a person who behaves affectedly in order to impress others.